# How to get Docker image to run on Mac M1

Tags: docker, apple-m1, azure-sql-edge

I'm trying to launch SQL Server for a technical test on my Macbook. Docker seemed to be best solution.

Tried using instructions from https://database.guide/how-to-install-sql-server-on-an-m1-mac-arm64/

Installed Docker okay.

Then tried to use:

```
sudo docker run --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=1' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=bigStrongPwd' -p 1433:1433 --name sqledge -d mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge
```

But when I tried to test the Docker using:

```
docker ps
```

The result was this:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

What's gone wrong?

Comment: Try removing the `docker run -d` option so it starts in the foreground and you can see its log message.  Or `docker ps -a` will show you stopped containers as well.

Comment: Thank you. I'm very new to docker so trying to work through it as quite important that I get it working, now and future.